# Why does installing a 12.10 virtual machine want to overwrite my 12.04 host installation?

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, i then installed virtual box. and windows xp in as a virtual machine. i also installed the additional guest add ons, and other extensions, which allows my virtual machine to use shared folders and usb devices.

I then downloaded Ubuntu 12.10. I installed it on the virtual box, but on the installation process, Ubuntu 12.10 says that it has detected my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and give me the option of erasing my 12.04.1 LTS and replacing it with the 12.10?

my question is :is virtual box serious?

what would happen if i choose that option saying "replace 12.04.1 with 12.10".. its just a virtual machine right?

Comment: it is possible that you had a previous, installed 12.04 installed on that virtualbox!? Could you provide a screenshot!?

Comment: Did you mount the Ubuntu .iso in your Virtual Box as a **virtual** CD-ROM?

Comment: ok., i will provide a scrren shot tommorrow.. promise.. please wait.. thanks for the concern guys..

Answer (score 1):

It's just a virtual machine, no worries. But I really don't understand how it detects our base 12.04.1 LTS. You simple MUST have installed 12.04.1 inside that virtual machine before, else it is simple NOT POSSIBLE.

Comment: thanks sir..  i will provide a screen shot tommorrow.. promise..

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, if you started installation process from within virtualbox indeed. So don't erase/overwrite your real installation!
Maybe it is a little confusing, but: your install CD is mounted twice, first in your real system, and then in your virtualbox. Both times it will present you the installer. So make sure you start the correct instance of the installer **from within virtualbox**. Then it is impossible that the installer sees your real ubuntu.  Let me think twice. Did you set your "/" directory as shared folder? This could change things, and the installer may "see" the real installation.

Comment: Shared folders can in no way be mounted when booting a VM for installation of an OS.

Comment: im so sorry., i dont know..

Comment: "Takkat wrote: Shared folders can in no way be mounted when booting a VM for installation of an OS."
Is this true even if he installs from within a previously installed virtual windows, all guest addons active and shared folder mounted? I have never had interest in so called WUBI way of installation so I can't tell wether it would touch the real ubuntu if the shared folder is set to /

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a Hypervisor can over ride its host operating system.

`What would happen if i choose that option saying "replace 12.04.1 with 12.10".`

It will replace what you have installed on your virtual hard drive with `12.10` you will get a operating system that has ended support and you wont be able to install any packages. keep the `12.04` on your Virtual Hard Drive.

[image]